# Updating UIImageView inside UIScrollView - image freezes on scroll

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview, freeze, nsurlrequest

I have UIImageView inside UIScrollView. UIImageView displays image which is constantly downloaded from the internet (stream opened by using NSURLConnection).

```
NSString surl = @"some valid url";
NSURL* nsurl = [NSURL URLWithString:surl];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

// this method will be called when every chunk of data is received
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // here I collect data and when i have enough
    // data to create UIImage i create one
}
```

Every time I receive data I pack it into a NSData and when I receive whole image I create UIImage from this NSData and then I set this image as image of UIImageView. Everything works fine, image updates as it should but when I touch screen and start to move content around (this UIImageView is always bigger than the screen and UIScrollView always fit whole screen) image updates stop and I see only last frame that was displayed at the time i clicked. This seems to be happening because my

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

stops being called. After releasing my finger from the screen method again receives data and image updates as it should. I have no idea why my NSURLConnection delegate method stops receiving data. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for `-[NSURLConnection initWithRequest:didReceiveData:]` says this:

> By default, for the connection to work correctly, the calling thread’s run loop must be operating in the default run loop mode.

I assume you are creating the `NSURLConnection` on the main thread.

When a `UIScrollView` is tracking a touch, it runs the run loop in different mode, not the default mode.  That's why you stop getting updates while you're touching the scroll view.  (This also causes `NSTimer`s to stop firing while you're touching a scroll view.)

I think you can set up your `NSURLConnection` to run in both the default mode and the scroll view tracking mode like this:

```
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request
    delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
[connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes];
[connection start];
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your user interaction is blocking your data update because they are both running on the main thread. I happen to have responded to a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328073/uitablewview-stops-renderings-during-scrolling/9330126#9330126) a couple not long ago.